# javascript split array depends on names

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a mybooks array, I'd like to separate it by the book's category.

```
var mybooks = [
    ['novel','BookName1','$20.00'],
    ['novel','BookName2','$24.00'],
    ['novel','BookName3','$34.00'],
    ['novel','BookName4','$31.00'],
    ['novel','BookName4','$38.00'],
    ['Biograph','BookName5','$28.00'],
    ['Biograph','BookName6','$48.00'],
    ['Biograph','BookName7','$50.00']
  ];
```

I made it this way.

```
 for(i=0; i<mybooks.length; i++){
        if ((mybooks[i][0]) == 'novel'){
        var books = mybooks[i];
        console.log(books);
       }
      };
```

console.log(books) prints

```
["novel", "BookName1", "$20.00"] 
["novel", "BookName2", "$24.00"]
["novel", "BookName3", "$34.00"]
["novel", "BookName4", "$31.00"] 
["novel", "BookName4", "$38.00"]
```

How can I make a global variable called 'splited' equals `books`

Comment: Make sure to have a look at my solution as well. It might teach you some JavaScript features ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a function return books:

```
var makeBooks = function(mybooks, type){
  var books=[];
  for(var i=0; i<mybooks.length; i++){
      if ((mybooks[i][0]) === type){
        books.push(mybooks[i]);
      }
  };
  return books;
}

window.splitted = makeBooks(mybooks, 'novel');
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am not sure exactly what you want as end result, but you could do something like this:

```
var splitted = mybooks.reduce(function (result, book) {
    var cat = book[0];

    if (!result[cat]) {
        result[cat] = [book];
    } else {
        result[cat].push(book);
    }

    return result;
}, {});

console.log(splitted); //all books splitted by categories
console.log(splitted.novel); //array of novels
console.log(splitted.Biograph); //array of Biograph
```

If you simply want to gather one category at a time, you could also use the `filter` function.

```
var novels = mybooks.filter(function (book) {
    return book[0] === 'novel';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var splitted=$.grep(mybooks,function(o){return (o[0]=='novel');});
```

Answer (score 1):

A fairly simple approach is:

```
var splitted = mybooks.filter(function(book) {return book[0] == 'novel';});
```

You could generalize it like this:

```
var byType = function(type) {return function(book) {return book[0] == type;};};
var bios = mybooks.filter(byType('Biograph'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to split the array by the book category? If so, it might be good to have a look at [object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals) instead

Comment: Thanks! but needs to be array for this case :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should arrange your book array by its type:

```
var mybooks = [
    ['novel','BookName1','$20.00'],
    ['novel','BookName2','$24.00'],
    ['novel','BookName3','$34.00'],
    ['novel','BookName4','$31.00'],
    ['novel','BookName4','$38.00'],
    ['Biograph','BookName5','$28.00'],
    ['Biograph','BookName6','$48.00'],
    ['Biograph','BookName7','$50.00']
  ];

var library = {}

for(i=0; i<mybooks.length; i++){
    var bookType = mybooks[i][0];
    if (typeof library[bookType]=='undefined')  
       library[bookType] = [];
    library[bookType].push(mybooks[i]);
}

console.log(library);
```